# How to make own device in Proteus

Tags: proteus

I made a scheme of 16-bit decoder in ISIS by AND's, XOR's etc. and now I want to use this scheme to make my own device. The block with ports. How to do this? I found videos, where people make block and its ports, but I have never seen how to use my own scheme to make my own device.

---

I've made this in ISIS:
[image]
It's working. And I need to take this circuit:
[image]

And make a simple block of it. Something like this:
[image]
Something, that I can save to library and use it later.

Comment: I don't know what's the difference... I have working decoder, but I can see the structure of it. And I want to make one block with few ports and save it to library, so I can use this block in other schemes without seeing what's in it.

Comment: I'm not native english speaker and I have never attended a subject about this. I'm just trying to learn something useful during holidays. So I'm sorry, that I can't express it properly. I probably don't even know how many posibilities here is, so I don't undertand, what's unclear about my question. What I want is very simple. I will try pictures. Just a second, please

Comment: The video I watched was http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-cv1bCiuKM.

Comment: No solution for this? I am searching for exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found one way.

Click the Subcircuit Mode icon here:
[image]

Then click on the screen, drag and create a box you want your device to look like. In the list you now have highlighted "DEFAULT". You choose "INPUT", click on your box, where you want ports to be. Than do the same with "OUTPUT". Give name to all ports by double clicking or using context menu and properties. You should get something like this:
[image]

Then click on the box and choose "Goto Child Sheet". There you can create the circuit. There you need to use INPUT and OUTPUT from the Terminals Mode (the icon right under the Subcircuit Mode icon in the first picture) and name them exactly the same as ports in the previous file. Be careful. Do not put ports on the wire. You have to connect them by the wire as any other device.

[image]

You can continue with building circuit in the parent sheet. I didn't find a way how to get it in to library to use it in other projects, but you can always copy it (Parent and Child sheet. If you copy only the box of circuit, the Child sheet will be empty).

I hope this is clear enough. My English is poor.

Comment: If you think that your problem is completely solved by method you explained in this answer, accept it by clicking on green tick mark.

Comment: Yes I end up on this way but adding it to a library or a simpler method to copy it (sometimes when copying the child sheet it conflicts with the designators that are already in use) would be great.

Comment: I think the "add to library" part is very relevant...

Comment: The other way is to made a Spice Block and use the "Library/Make Device" menu...