# Hierarchical design in Isis Proteus

Tags: proteus

I am designing a big digital circuit in Proteus and I need to create my own components because I am going to reuse them lots of times for example 32 bit adders, big buffers, etc). I read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74980/how-to-make-own-device-in-proteus%20%22%22) but he got no answer so I created a `sub-circuit instead`:

[image]

The problem is that when I create multiple sub-circuits bus names enter in conflict because they have the same name, and I want to duplicate them so I will need to create a sub-circuit changing the bus name (with the labels inside each sub-circuit) for every new sub-circuit I add.

How can I solve this problem? Is any workaround for this? Aren't big designs possible in Proteus?

Answer (score 6):

From answer posted [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166018/how-to-define-a-primitive-device-in-proteus)
It's in the Proteus Help file:

SCHEMATIC CAPTURE HELP (F1) -> MULTI-SHEET DESIGNS -> Hierarchical Designs

See the section "Module Components":

> Any ordinary component can be made into a module by setting the Attach Hierarchy Module checkbox on the Edit Component dialogue form.
>   The component's value is taken to be the name for the associated circuit,
>   and the component's reference serves as the instance name.

after this you can use your new implementation of that component with your new name. for making it available at library see "External Modules" section of proteus help.