# How to define a primitive device in Proteus?

Tags: proteus

I'm trying to make my own full adder and some other devices as a sub-circuit in "Proteus" and use them several times in a bigger circuit.

The problem is when you copy a sub-circuit you need to rename all of its inner parts, otherwise, the parts with a same name in two sub-circuits would be considered as one, therefore you'd get some errors.

So I'd like to know if there is a way to define a full adder of my own and use it like "74LS183" which is a primitive device, and by primitive I mean it has been defined in the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the Proteus Help file:

SCHEMATIC CAPTURE HELP (F1) -> MULTI-SHEET DESIGNS -> Hierarchical Designs

See the section "External Modules" - you should be able to define the child sheet as a .MOD file, then use the Make Device command on the parent component and use include the .MOD file there.

I've never done it before, but I'll try it now. Sounds like it should be simple...

Comment: I do the same but can't use those components on other schematics . I don't know it's acceptable or not , but here is the link I ask my question : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195767/component-ic-does-not-work-for-different-schematics