# How to resize component in Proteus 8.1?

Tags: proteus

I have this situation on Proteus 8.1:

[image]

The AND components are TOO big, so I want to make it smaller.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Forget it.

The solution I found was to create an IC with all this components.

Found the answer here:

[How to make own device in Proteus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74980/how-to-make-own-device-in-proteus?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

In any reasonable CAD system, you can make your own schematic symbols (and PCB footprints), so you should be able to create smaller AND gate symbols, but you probably can't shrink or stretch the existing symbols.